# Selecting object in WorldScaleARexample

Tags: mapbox

I am working on an AR app in Unity and want to display information of an object. To display said information, the user has to be able to click/select that object. 
I cannot find the line of code that creates the objects.

I have tried to use a snippet of the ARTabletopKit that handles the user's input to select an object. 
If I am correct, the problem is that I cannot use the DebugCanvas-GameObject of the WorldScaleAR example as it does not contain any of the actual game objects.

As far as I can see the objects are created and placed here:

```
unityTile.Initialize(_map, tileId, _map.WorldRelativeScale, _map.AbsoluteZoom, _map.LoadingTexture); 
PlaceTile(tileId, unityTile, _map);
```

At last I expect the method EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject() to return true.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add a `[GameObjectModifier][1]` to handle the onClick. You can configure the modifiers to be added at runtime on the game objects in the [Map Features](https://docs.mapbox.com/unity/maps/overview/map-features/) area of the AbstractMap.cs script.

I would take a look at how it's implemented on the [Data Explorer example](https://docs.mapbox.com/unity/maps/examples/data-explorer/).